# My artifactory-pro-7.59.11 which runs inside a docker container through docker-compose is not able to connect to an external postgresql database

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose, artifactory

```
Preparing to run Artifactory in Docker
Running as uid=1030(artifactory) gid=1030(artifactory) groups=1030(artifactory)
Dockerfile for this image can found inside the container.
To view the Dockerfile: 'cat /docker/artifactory-pro/Dockerfile.artifactory'.
Resolved .shared.database.type (postgresql) from /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/system.yaml
Resolved .shared.database.url (__sensitive_key_hidden___) from /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/system.yaml
Waiting for DB postgresql to be ready on 5.4.3.2/5432 for 30 seconds
Copying Artifactory bootstrap files
2023-07-26T09:30:01.843Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [systemYamlHelper.sh:607       ] [main] - Resolved .shared.node.id (artifactory.example.com) from /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/system.yaml
2023-07-26T09:30:02.017Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [systemYamlHelper.sh:607       ] [main] - Resolved .shared.node.ip (1.2.3.4) from /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/system.yaml
2023-07-26T09:30:04.508Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [systemYamlHelper.sh:607       ] [main] - Resolved .shared.database.type (postgresql) from /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/system.yaml
2023-07-26T09:30:04.999Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [systemYamlHelper.sh:607       ] [main] - Resolved .shared.database.url (__sensitive_key_hidden___) from /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/system.yaml
2023-07-26T09:30:05.333Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [systemYamlHelper.sh:607       ] [main] - Resolved .shared.database.password (__sensitive_key_hidden___) from /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/system.yaml
```

This logs goes on infinitely.

I have validated the system.yaml, the database credentials, iptables.
I have also checked that the packet is reaching to the external database on port 5432 from the docker container that means the network is configured correctly.

I also added some postgres config like:

```
<postgres_mount>/data/postgresql.conf listen_addresses='*'

pg_hba.conf

host  artifactory       artifactory     1.2.3.4/32 md5
```

Here is my system.yaml

```
shared:
  database:
    type: postgresql
    driver: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: jdbc:postgresql://5.4.3.2:5432/artifactory
    username: artifactory
    password: password
  node:
    ip: 1.2.3.4
    id: artifactory.example.com
    name: artifactory
router:
  entrypoints:
    externalPort: 8081
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3'
services:
  artifactory:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}/jfrog/artifactory-pro:${ARTIFACTORY_VERSION}
    container_name: artifactory
    environment:
      - JF_ROUTER_ENTRYPOINTS_EXTERNALPORT=${JF_ROUTER_ENTRYPOINTS_EXTERNALPORT}
    ports:
      - ${JF_ROUTER_ENTRYPOINTS_EXTERNALPORT}:${JF_ROUTER_ENTRYPOINTS_EXTERNALPORT} # for router communication
      - 8081:8081 # for artifactory communication
    volumes:
      - ${ROOT_DATA_DIR}/var:/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    restart: always
    logging:
      driver: json-file
      options:
        max-size: "50m"
        max-file: "10"
    ulimits:
      nproc: 65535
      nofile:
        soft: 32000
        hard: 40000
```

I'm using artifactory template to setup.
Here you can find one for docker-compose https://jfrog.com/download-jfrog-platform/

Comment: Why do you think it can't connect to the db ? There should be messages in the log in such cases

Comment: I don't know. I been stuck here for days. 
The only logs that I get is written above.

Comment: I have checked locally and got the following error `[RETRY] Initiating database connection: failed to connect to host=127.0.0.1 user=artifactory database=artifactory: dial error (dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5432: connect: connection refused). Retrying in 1s ... (2/120) [database]`

Comment: Did you mount system.yaml ? Please share you docker-compose.yaml file

Comment: May be the database was not started, Can you please check the database log? If its online try to connect using pgadmin locally

Comment: Hey @JaganSekaran the database is up and running. I have also successfully connected to the database locally through pgAdmin.

Comment: @ALex_hha I did mount the system.yaml and I have added docker-compose file in my question explanation.

Comment: @AshishChaurasia your compose file doesn't have the database service. are you running postgres on a separate docker-compose? If yes, both service will have different docker network. 
Artifactory and Postgresql should be on same network to communicate. 
https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Comment: @JaganSekaran the database is running in another VM and the connection is enabled between both the servers.

Comment: @AshishChaurasia where you able to reach the DB server from Artifactory docker container? Try to do a telnet to the dbIP:port